# The workflow of loading images as TensorFlow dataset and feed into Keras model.fit?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-datasets

I'm working on a remote sensing dataset that requires me manually load two folders of input images of `(1024, 1024, 3)` and concatenate each pair into a `(1024, 1024, 6)` input. Each label is in the format of `(1024, 1024, 1)`.

Therefore the final feedable `tf.data.Dataset` should be in the dimension of `((None, 1024, 1024, 6), (None, 1024, 1024, 1))` where `None` is the batch dimension.

Following the guide on [Loading images into TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images) and [Train and evaluate with Keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate), my dataset was in the shape of `<ParallelMapDataset shapes: ((None, None, 6), (None, None, 1)), types: (tf.float32, tf.float32)>`.

Therefore it fails to pass into `model.fit()` function, and yields the error of `'ParallelMapDataset' object has no attribute 'ndim'`.

#### Relevant code:

```
base_path = './LEVIR-CD/'

train_path_list = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(base_path + 'train/A/*.png')
test_path_list = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(base_path + 'test/A/*.png')
val_path_list = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(base_path + 'val/A/*.png')

def process_path(a_path):
    b_path = tf.strings.regex_replace(a_path, '/A/', '/B/')
    label_path = tf.strings.regex_replace(a_path, '/A/', '/label/')

    a = tf.image.decode_png(tf.io.read_file(a_path), channels=3) / 255
    b = tf.image.decode_png(tf.io.read_file(b_path), channels=3) / 255
    label = tf.image.decode_png(tf.io.read_file(label_path), channels = 1) / 255
    return concatenate([a, b], axis = 2), label

train_ds = train_path_list.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
test_ds = test_path_list.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_path_list.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

```
isinstance(train_ds, tf.data.Dataset) # ==> True
model.fit(train_ds) # ==> Error
```

[image: Sample data pair]

**Update:**
`tf.image.resize(a, [1024, 1024])` which resizes these 1024*1024 images into the same size will solve the missing dimension issue but the error remains.

Comment: Did you forget to use `.batch(BATCH_SIZE)` ? It could explain the missing 4th dimension

Comment: @Kh4zit I forgot to include those lines in the question but including batching and shuffling makes no difference, only the error message turns into `'BatchDataset' object has no attribute 'ndim'`